# Sentry sdk timeout setting

Tags: python, django, sentry

I have a django app and I was using raven to send events to sentry:

**settings.py**

```py
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
   'dsn': '***',
   'timeout': 10,
   'transport': 'raven.transport.requests.RequestsHTTPTransport'
}
```

Now, as I'm switching to newly released sentry-sdk, how do I set timeout?
Can't find it neither in docs nor in sentry-sdk code.

```py
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration
sentry_sdk.init(
   dsn="***",
   integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
   timeout=10
)
```

Comment: Ok, looks like the only way to have timeouts is to write another transport. Current HttpTransport is on urllib3 and doesn't expect timeouts

Comment: `timeout` was broken in raven-python for quite a while. I believe you're supposed to add it as a query param to the DSN as per https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/429. I suspect your code for setting the timeout option does not change Raven's behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a custom transport like this:

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.transport import HttpTransport

class NewHttpTransport(HttpTransport):
    def _get_pool_options(self, *a, **kw):
        rv = HttpTransport._get_pool_options(self, *a, **kw)
        rv['timeout'] = 3
        return rv

sentry_sdk.init(transport=NewHttpTransport)
```